# How do you calculate the potential elastic energy in only one of the springs of a series? What about if they were connected in paralel?

Tags: energy, potential-energy, spring, elasticity

Given the elastic constants of 2 springs (k1=125N/m, k2=200N/m), how can you calculate the ratio between the potential elastic energy stored in the first spring (k1) when it is grouped in series with the second, and potential elastic energy when the two are grouped in parallel? The same object is hanged on both systems, making the deformatory force equal in both scenarios

Comment: Think about the physics. When in series, what is equal for the two? When in parallel, what is equal for the two? You should be able to solve this.

Comment: What do you mean by equal of the two?

Comment: There must be some physical quantity that, in those scenarios, are equal for the two springs.

Comment: Ah sorry i forgot to add information about the force. It is the same in both scenarios

Comment: Duplicate of [energy stored in series springs vs energy stored in parallel springs](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/305060/energy-stored-in-series-springs-vs-energy-stored-in-parallel-springs)